# Very slow app startup when using dll built with VS 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, iis

I have a class library project consisted purely of xml files with build action set to Embedded resource. Application reads these files during startup.
When I build this project inside VS 2010, deploy this project to IIS, application starts very slowly ( > 5 min).
When I open same solution with VS 2012, build class library project and deploy dll to IIS, application starts for ~20 seconds.
Inspection of both dll-s with ILSpy didn't find any differences. Also, dlls size is identical. This is profiler trace of slow startup:

[image]

Any ideas what could be the cause this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the target platforms the same? .NET version the same? Both build in Release mode?

Comment: Target platforms and .NET versions are the same. Both are built with same build configuration.